# Why isn't the address for billing copying to shipping?

Tags: javascript

So I know that fields are properly named, but javascript is still not copying info over when the check box is checked. I have double checked and everything matches up in the fields.

JavaScript:

```
function FillShiping(f) {
    if(f.shipingtoo.checked == true) {
        f.shipto.value = f.billto.value;
        f.shipaddress.value = f.Address.value;
        f.shipcity.value = f.City.value;
        f.shipstate.value = f.State.value;
        f.shipzip.value = f.Zip.value;
    }

    if(f.shipingtoo.checked == false) {
        f.shipto.value = '';
        f.shipaddress.value = '';
        f.shipcity.value = '';
        f.shipstate.value = '';
        f.shipzip.value = '';
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="fb-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="Fillshiping(this.form)" name="shipingtoo">
    <span class="fb-fieldlabel" id="item61_0_span">Check this if shipping address is same
                        as billing address </span>
    </label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your html looks pretty broken, try fixing that first

Comment: Your HTML is all sorts of invalid.

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. It seems you did not include the full HTML here and behavioral bugs are easier to spot when we can actually run some code.

Comment: Aside from telling me it's broken, any insight into what needs to fix? I am not a dev.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f3vGx/

Comment: We can't tell you how to fix HTML from just this snippet. Please run the page through [the W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) (or similar) and this will help you fix it.

Comment: Voting to close this since typos are too localized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The console shows the error:

> ReferenceError: Fillshiping is not defined

You named the function `FillShiping`, but you are calling `Fillshiping(this.form)` (lowercase `s`).

After [correcting your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3vGx/1/) *and* [naming the function properly, it seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/f3vGx/2/).

---

Use your browser's developer tools to debug your code, it's invaluable.

Comment: Thank you, i know it's usually something silly I'm missing, and I just don't always know where to look, thanks for the tip on browser tools.

Comment: @JeremyChambers - I changed more and commented in the fiddle, resulting in a [third version](http://jsfiddle.net/f3vGx/3/).

Comment: @StephenP I appreciate that. I work for a non profit, and try to manage our site and development as best I can, I always appreciate it when others are willing and able to help us figure stuff out.